# ModX gives me empty page of my document

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-templates, modx-resources, modx-chunks

I have Document- `"news"`, where are a lot of `articles`(children documents), if I click on some article, ModX gives me empty page with the current `alias` name in url. Error Log shows me

```
[2015-09-02 17:06:38] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not retrieve data to cache for resource 466
[2015-09-02 17:06:40] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not retrieve data to cache for resource 466
```

resource 466- this is my article. What can I do to solve this problem? 
P.S. I have already deleted all cache files(by my hands). On my local server all is OK! Templates are the same on web server and on my local... 
 Thank you.

Comment: any errors in  apache logs?

Comment: What happens when you directly preview one of the child resources from within manager?

Comment: what was the issue in the end?

Answer (score 0):

If these resources are static (binary files such as images, PDFs) try setting them uncached. I had the same issue and that fixed it for me.

[image]